# Flying Saucer hide header and footer on first page

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

I've been playing with the flying saucer R8 and tried to ***hide header and footer from the front page*** of my PDF.

I followed that [hint](http://groups.google.com/group/flying-saucer-users/browse_thread/thread/1dc1589ffb7b5a6) tried to follow the W3C specifications for the **content: element()** [(W3C running elements)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#running-elements) in my print.css. It is described that the following should solve my problem:

```
@page { @top-center { content: element(header, first-except) }}
```

But it seems that this is not yet implemented in R8. So I tried the approach above with the **set-string** method.

```
#header { set-string: header content() }
@page { @top-center { content: string(header, first-except) }}
```

But nothing gets rendered, **content: string()** seems to be broken, since whatever I put in there will not be rendered:

```
@page { @top-center { content: "foo" string(header, first-except) }} /*broken*/
@page { @top-center { content: "foo" string(header) }} /*broken*/
@page { @top-center { content: "foo" }} /*works!*/
```

So has anyone an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, the soulution was easy. I copied it from the flying saucer manual sources [link](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/doc/guide/users-guide-r8.xil)

I had to do the following:

add a second footer without the page numbering:

```
<div id="normalFooter" style="position: running(normalFooter);">
    <div class="footerContent">fancy stuff</div>
    page <span class="page"/> of <span class="pagecount"/> 
</div>
<div id="firstPageFooter" style="position: running(firstPageFooter);">
    <div class="footerContent">fancy stuff</div>
</div>
```

The trick is the CSS **@page :first**:

```
@page {     
    @bottom-right {
        content: element(normalFooter);
    }
} 

@page :first {      
    @bottom-right {
        content: element(firstPageFooter);
    }
}
```

There is a normal footer for all the pages except the first one, that comes with a different footer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.  The key thing I missed initially was the string-set property on the #cover element.  It also shows how to do the page counter.  The #cover element is on my cover page resulting in the counter incrementing on page one even though the footer is not being shown.

```
        div.header {
            display: block;
            font-size: 8pt;
            position: running(header);
        }

        div.header .project-date {
            padding-left: 8px;
        }

        div.header .project-name {
            padding-left: 4px;
        }

        div.footer {
            font-size: 8pt;
            display: block;
            position: running(footer);
        }

        div.footer .page-number:before {
            counter-increment: section;
            content: counter(section);
        }


        @page {
            size: 8.5in 11in;
            margin: 1cm;
            @top-center { content: element(header, last-except)}

            @bottom-center { content: element(footer, last-except)}

        }

        #cover {
            string-set: footer header;
            counter-increment: section;
        }
```